# search for colored string in Linux bash stdout with python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I want to parse Linux bash application stdout with Python.
I read the stdout into a string with Popen function from subproocess library in Python
I need to know how can I search for red color string in my bash application stdout in python?
How can I search for "item number" with their color e.g. reading red string into string?

[image]

Comment: Pipe the output to a file. The colors should be recognizable by control characters.

Comment: Thanks for you attention, would you explain more?what are those control character(please with python doc reference)

Comment: This is not a Python problem, Also take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors .

Answer (score 1):

A red 2, for example, is probably a byte string like `\e[31m2\e[0m`, where `\e` represents ASCII escape. (The 0 may or may not be present.) These are the actual bytes that are written to the terminal; the terminal then treats them as instructions to modify how to display the regular text. That is, instead of displaying the literal characters `\e`, `[`, `3`, `1`, and `m`, they are treated as an instruction to display the following text in red. `\e[0m` (or `\e[m`) likewise are not displayed, but as an instruction to display the following text in the terminal's default colors and style.

Comment: what does "\e[31m2\e[0m" mean? is this ASCII equivalent of "red 2"?

Comment: The escape codes are part of the ANSI standard. ANSI-compliant terminals do not treat them as literal bytes to display.

Comment: How can I find and search for such pattern(red two) in  a string with python functions?

Comment: `\e` is a character, just like `a` or `3`. You just need to search for that particular substring.